# Default VirtualHost redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, redirect

I need your help guys.

I have a server running Apache 2 and in there I've multiple vhosts bound to different domains. I want that the default vhost (so every address not bounded with a vhost) redirects to one of this domain, call it maindomain.com.
Previously, I put in the default vhost config a redirect to maindomain.com and **everything was working fine**.

The problem is that now **I changed the hostname of the system** (I had to do that!) to maindomain.com. So, if I understood correctly, now maindomain.com is implicitly the default domain (infact I fell in a redirect loop issue).

I fixed this issue by setting maindomain.com location as default vhost. Things work but I get no redirect. If you, for example, visit www.maindomain.com (or any address not bound with a vhost) you visualize the correct site but in address bar you still see www.maindomain.com and NOT maindomain.com.

So, how I can fix this avoiding redirect loops?

1. Is it possible to disable the fact that the hostname behaves like default vhost in Apache?
2. Or, alternatively, how I can display maindomain.com in the address bar when someone connects using another address?

I hope that you can help me out, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, if a request comes in for a name for which there is no explicit `VirtualHost`, then Apache will use the default `VirtualHost` to handle the request. So, you're not seeing a redirect for URLs that don't have their own `VirtualHost` because you changed the default *from* the one that redirects *to* the one that just serves the content.

If you know which domains you're going to be handling, you should use wildcards to catch unexpected subdomains, e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName         *.maindomain.com
    ServerAlias        otherdomain.com *.otherdomain.com
    RedirectPermanent  /  http://maindomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    maindomain.com
    ... rest of VirtualHost ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure how this differs from what you had in the first place, though.

Comment: Wildcards can be a possible (partial) workaround. But the problem is that Apache recognize as default the domain that matchs the machine's hostname

Comment: I don't think that's true. [The Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) say (emphasis mine): "If the request contained an unknown or no Host: header it is always served from the primary name-based vhost (the vhost for that address/port **appearing first in the configuration file**)". Check the order of your VHosts?

Comment: Well, the configuration was working fine until I changed the hostname. After I changed hostname to maindomain.com apache didn't recognize the vhost associated with maindomain.com. Vhosts order is correct (was working before!). By the way I partially solved using wildcards as you suggested